# Why was my "rude" flag on an answer containing "lol" declined?

Tags: discussion, declined-flags

This answer had a "lol", and I can only assume it's aimed at the asker since nobody else had posted.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/60141302/5159168

After some other comments I commented to the answerer that laughing at someone's question is not nice. (Or something like it)

The post was deleted, alright I thought.

Then it came back. I flagged as rude.

I see the answer is edited to remove the "lol", my comment saying it's not nice to laugh at questions is also gone.

Good job, right?

**declined - a moderator reviewed your flag, but found no evidence to support it**

How did that happen?
Is that really how we are supposed to start our answers to new users here? To laugh at them?

Comment: It's just noise and definitely deserves to be edited out (I'd argue the same for emojis but apparently people disagree) but I don't think it constitutes a rude flag here (although whether a flag is appropriate in such a situation is context-dependent).

Comment: The question should’ve been closed, not answered. The text makes little sense, doesn’t match the example given, and introduces spurious code that seems to have no bearing on the question. But I don’t frequent the `php` tag; maybe this is a “good” question there...

Comment: No needed to call mod you had an option to edit my answer or tell me to do that.

Comment: @dlk I said it's not nice to laugh but you didn't edit it out.

Comment: Original posters are notified when an edit is made. At that point they can choose to learn what not to do. A flag is only warranted if the poster keeps bringing it back or the post should just be deleted.

Comment: @Andreas the fact they didn't immediately edit it out is no reason for calling a mod. You are not emperor to the universe, other humans do not have to obey you whenever you say something. They could have disagreed that it's not ok to laugh, they could have simply not seen the message, they could have had no idea what you were talking about since they did not *actually feel like they were laughing at someone*.

Answer (score 23):

We could do with a lot more editing in this case and at *least* five orders of magnitude less hand wringing.

You could edit out one word or one sentence if you believe it's chatter or irrelevant to the main point of the answer.

We don't require a Meta post asking us we're cool with laughing at OPs since it's something we can fix without needing to call mods.

Comment: Spot on.  Don't use a sledgehammer when a ball peen hammer will suffice.

Comment: ***You could edit out one word or one sentence if you believe it's chatter or irrelevant to the main point of the answer.*** So just editing out stuff is the correct way to go? There is no need to learn? Just like having your driving instructor always in the car doing everything for you without saying what or why? Alright, got it.

Comment: I am realy sorry because of causing this problem! I didnt laugh at OP and I never do that. I just put `lol` because of words were funny, I didn't think it would be perceived or  rude. @Andreas could warn me to edit my answer or edit my answer, before starting this, I have way and years to go, for laughing at someone. once again all of the world is not english and we all can't speak perfect english, you must be understanding us. I learn from my mistakes. Once again I am so sorry because of causing problem.

Comment: @Andreas:  This is not a driving school.  This is a site which explicitly puts editing questions and answers up front as a first class citizen.  Calling moderators for *exceptional* things - the stuff we normal users can't handle - is the ideal pattern here.  If you wanted to "teach" someone about this, you could've edited the answer *and* left a comment as to why you edited it.